# Calling function in Swift extension from Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridge, uidevice

I have this extension written in Swift [pseudo code]:

```
import Foundation
import UIKIt

extension UIDevice {

    var modelName: String {
        var systemInfo = utsname()...

    }

    @objc class func getPlatformName() -> NSString {
        return UIDevice.modelName;
    }
}
```

I want to call `getPlatformName` from objective-c. I include the `ProjectName-Swift.h` file in my obj-c file. I tried:

```
NSString* strDeviceName = [UIDevice currentDevice].getPlatformName
```

but compiler choked on that, saying `getPlatformName` not found on object of type `UIDevice`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You defined getPlatformName as a *class method,* so it should be `[UIDevice getPlatformName]`

Comment: I tried that before I posted (should of added that) and it still errors.

Comment: Show how you tried it – I am sure that it works.

Comment: NSString* strDeviceName = [UIDevice getPlatformName];

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is, what we use to call in the Army, operator error. I forgot to include the file in one of our targets (we have 30) and if you look at the import I have a typo  - UIKIt...

Comment: Sorry for extending this, but new to Swift. I had to make the function public to return the modelName var, how could I make them class functions and return that var?

Comment: I’d suggest you delete/edit this question rather than asking new, different question in comments.

Comment: Why define function at all? Just define your computed `modelName` ivar as `@objc`, itself, and then you bypass function altogether, accessing it from ObjC with `NSString *string = [UIDevice currentDevice].modelName;`. Second, why class function/property versus instance function/property? It seems like you're describing properties of the `current`/`currentDevice`, so making it class function seems wrong to me.